# Convergence in $C([0,T_0],L^2)$ and uniform boundedness in $C([0,T_0],H^2)$ gives convergence in $C([0,T_0],H^1)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a compact set of $\mathbb{R}$ and $s\geq 1$. Let 
$$
v_n\in C([0,T_0];H^{s+1}(\Omega)).
$$ 
Also $\sup_{t\in[0,T_0]} ||v_n||_{H^{s+1}(\Omega)}\leq M$, $M$ is a constant.

We are also given that 
$$ 
v_n\longrightarrow v \quad\text{   in  }  \quad C([0,T_0];L^2(\Omega)).
$$
How do I show that 
$$
v_n\longrightarrow v\quad\text{   in  }  \quad C([0,T_0];H^s(\Omega))?
$$

*Note*: This problem is a portion of a paper I am reading. As an argument for this problem, the authors write ‘interpolating the given convergence with the uniform bound estimates’. I don’t know what they mean by this.

Comment: I edit your question to make it a bit more readable, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @BigbearZzz Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure there are no typos? In the current form, this would imply that every every sequence that converges in $L^2$ and is bounded in $H^s$ also converges in $H^s$. This is not the case.

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks a lot. I looked into it and made the changes. I hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not exactly sure how to apply Aubin-Lions here, as suggest by BibgearZzz. However, I think what the authors mean by ‘interpolating the given convergence with the uniform bound estimates’ is the following.

First note that $(v_n(t))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a subsequence that converges to $v(t)$ weakly in $H^{s+1}(\Omega)$. In particular, $v(t)\in H^{s+1}(\Omega)$ and $\|v(t)\|_{H^{s+1}}\leq M$. Then you can use that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $C>0$ such that
$$
\|f\|_{H^{s}}\leq \epsilon\|f\|_{H^{s+1}}+C\|f\|_{L^2}
$$
for all $f\in H^{s+1}$ (I don't know a name for this inequality, but it's proof boils down to partial integration + Young's inequality - it's Theorem 7.28 in Gilbarg-Trudinger).

Applied to the case at hand, you get
$$
\|v_n(t)-v(t)\|_{H^s}\leq \epsilon\|v_n(t)-v(t)\|_{H^{s+1}}+C\|v_n(t)-v(t)\|_{L^2}\leq 2\epsilon M+C\|v_n-v\|_{C([0,T_0];L^2)}.
$$
Letting $n\to\infty$ and then $\epsilon\searrow 0$ yields the desired conclusion.

Comment: A short question: Shouldn't it be $||f||_{H^s}$ instead of $||f||_{H^{s+1}}$ on the left hand side of your first inequality?

Comment: @F. Conrad You are right, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got time to look into detail yet, but I think you probably need [Aubin–Lions lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aubin%E2%80%93Lions_lemma) or something very similar. The bound on $\partial_t v_n$ is crucial for the method to work.